# PHP external JSON into Vuejs list

Tags: javascript, php, json, vue.js

This gives me the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

I am trying to retrieve the external JSON via php and serve up a Vue component to list of the names of the campaigns which are under "data" in the JSON.

I'm having trouble figuring this out. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me!

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the campaigns.
 *
 * Template name: Campaigns
 *
 */

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://brain.snappykraken.dev/templates",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$campaigns = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
}



?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
              <campaigns list="<?php echo json_encode($campaigns); ?>"></campaigns>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<template id="campaigns-template">
    <h1>My Campaigns</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" v-for="campaigns in list">
            {{ campaign.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>
Vue.config.devtools = true
Vue.component('campaigns', {
    template: '#campaigns-template',
    props: ['list'],
    created() {
        this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
    }
});
new Vue({
  el: 'body'
});
</script>
```

This is the JSON that is being pulled in:

{"total":2,"per_page":15,"current_page":1,"last_page":1,"next_page_url":null,"prev_page_url":null,"from":1,"to":2,"data":[{"id":1,"fleet_id":1,"audience_id":1,"name":"Investing Extremes","description":"This is the description for the campaign yeah uhuhuhuh!","zapier":"","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-08-11 00:31:34","updated_at":"2016-08-11 00:31:34"},{"id":2,"fleet_id":1,"audience_id":1,"name":"Investing Mediocres","description":"This is the description for the other","zapier":"","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-08-11 00:31:34","updated_at":"2016-08-11 00:31:34"}]}

Note: I am using the latest vue.min.js and vue-resource.min.js

Comment: Try `<campaigns list="<?php echo $campaigns; ?>"></campaigns>`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the trick. Thanks for trying.